# Sharing my VPN provider to multiple pcs / tables / tv

Tags: networking, router, vpn, proxy, tv

Let me try to explain what I want to do, and maybe a solution (but it didn't work for me).

Basically I pay a VPN Provider, if I install the client I can connect this pc with their Service, everything fine.

But what I would like to have is. I would like to create a virtual server (docker, proxmox) where the server is always connected to the VPN. While the rest of my network is using my normal provider.

Now the idea is, if for what ever reason I need to use the VPN ip, lets say on my mobile phone, I want to some how - magically - connect to the virtual server and use its IP to surf the internet and if I am done I would disconnect and use my normal Ip.

I would like to do this magically transition as smooth as possible and as available as possible, means also on my Samsung Tv, which is very limited with apps & co.

So my idea was basically this.
Server has VPN client installed and configured.
Server has a Proxy Server installed.

Now every client uses the normal network and if I need to use the VPN I would like to add a Proxy Server IP (from my virtual server) and this device would now connect to the server and use the VPN. The idea with the proxy is that every device, programm usually supports Proxy Servers, and usually you can even save the IP there. Which would be just a flag on/off to toggle between them.

I tried several tutorials, how to configure VPN clients or how to setup Proxy Servers, everything works on its own. But I did not find a tutorial describing both of them.

I do not even know the term how you would describe this.
I am not a pro in this regards, but have a bit knowledge with linux, docker, proxmox.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could just use one PC (or even a Raspberry Pi) to act as a "mobile hotspot", i.e., VPN to PC --> WiFi .

Comment: @BlindSpots : I use proton vpn and my Tv doesn't have an vpn app. 
I used multiple proxy servers, like squid.
I never used a docker vpn client, thats actually a good idea, maybe I should try.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik : Honestly I tried this in the past, I never had luck getting the Rasyberry Pi working as mobile hotspot because usually needs like 2 Wlans, and usually Raspberry has only one. And my Proxmox has no wlan.

Comment: You might look at running something like [tprasadtp/protonvpn-docker](https://github.com/tprasadtp/protonvpn-docker) you could run a single compose file with both the VPN and the Proxy services.  PS: haven't run that container just found it Googling

Comment: BTW, you do realize that most VPN connections are  *s l o w e r*  than direct to ISP? Video may be unwatchable.